# IBM Cloud: How do I retrieve information about private endpoints from credentials or service bindings?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have my account enabled for VRF and private service endpoints. When I create service credentials, typically I only see URIs for the public endpoint. How can my bound app working with the credentials obtain the URI for the enabled private endpoint?

Here are the credentials for a Watson Assistant instance enabled for private endpoints. It only has the public URI.

```
{
  "apikey": "myApiKeyValueWouldBeHere",
  "iam_apikey_description": "Auto-generated for key 9197a2b1-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7a99966e0056",
  "iam_apikey_name": "Service credentials test",
  "iam_role_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam::::serviceRole:Manager",
  "iam_serviceid_crn": "crn:v1:bluemix:public:iam-identity::a/1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz::serviceid:ServiceId-a2072c22-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx3a714f525",
  "url": "https://api.eu-de.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/932d30c1-xxxx-xxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to generate credentials for private endpoints from both the UI, CLI, terraform, etc.

For the [CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_service_key_create), add the `--service-endpoint` parameter with value **private**:

```
ibmcloud resource service-key-create myCreds Manager 
 --instance-name myWatsonAssistant_PLUS --service-endpoint private
```

The above also works with [`ibmcloud resource service-binding-create`](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_service_binding_create).

When using the IBM Cloud console (UI) and the add credentials dialog, go to the **advanced options** and add **inline configuration options**. There, add the following value:

```
{"service-endpoints":"private"}
```

This will lead to credentials for the private endpoint be generated. You can pass the same key / value in other interfaces like the API or in [terraform](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/terraform?topic=terraform-resource-mgmt-resources#resource-key).

The generated credentials have the additional key **private_endpoint** set to **true**.

Answer (score 2):

Your private network endpoint should be displayed in the Manage tab for the service instance.

> In the service details page, click the **Manage** tab, and then click **Private Network Endpoint**.

See [Public and private network endpoints](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-public-private-endpoints#adding-a-private-network-endpoint) and [Protecting sensitive information](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-security) [in Assistant].

Comment: I asked about the credentials and service bindings. They have the endpoint included, but IMHO only the public one.

Comment: You say that the account is enabled. But did you add a private endpoint to the instance? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson?topic=watson-public-private-endpoints#adding-a-private-network-endpoint.

Comment: yes, the service was enabled for private endpoints. It is visible in the service dashboard, but not in the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. The `credentials` tab usually shows multiple credentials, do you see both `private` and `public` or just `public` ones?

Comment: I can see autogenerated credentials, but my user-generated creds only have the public endpoint